# Converting C code to MIPS Assembly Language

Tags: c, assembly, mips

Here's the C code:

```
int A[10];
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;

while (i<10){
sum += A[i++];
sum *= 2;
}
```

Here's my take at converting into MIPS:

```
**Reg. Allocation Table:
A = $s1
sum = $s2
i = $s3
10 = $s4**

loop: beq $s3, $s4, endloop 

"here's where i get stuck, inside the while loop."

j: loop
endloop:
```

I understand that in a basic while loop such as: `i = $s1`, `5 = $s3`

```
i=0;
while(i != 5)
i=i+1;

addi $s1, $zero, 0 #i=0

loop: beq $s1, $s3, endloop
add   $s1, $s1, 1
j     loop:

endloop:
```

I'm just having trouble, or having a hard time comprehending a slightly more difficult loop where `sum+= A[i++];` and `sum*= 2;` are introduced.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm not looking for a complete solution, so please help me *think*.

Thank you!

Comment: `sum *= 2` is `mul <register that holds sum> <register that holds sum> 2`. Then `sum += A[i++]` is `add sum, sum, <address of A>(i)>` (maybe a slightly different syntax, depending on how your assembler handles memory addressing), followed by `add i, i, 1` (where `i` is the register holding the value of `i`).

Comment: Why isn't your compiler doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break it down:

`sum += A[i++];` becomes `sum = sum + A[i]; i = i + 1;` which in MIPS assembly could be expressed:

```
add $t0 $s3 $s1 #index A at i
lw  $t1 0($t0)  #load A at i

add  $s2 $s2 $t1 #add A[i] to sum
addi $s3 $s3 1   #increment i

sll $s2 $s2 1 #double sum
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will go over this tonight and make sense of it. I appreciate your help!